# What are RowMapper, ResultSetExtractor, bind variables and query types?

Tags: java, spring, dao, model-binding, jdbctemplate

I know how to use JDBC Template and DAO, but I still have questions regarding it:

1. What's the use of `RowMapper` and `ResultSetExtractor`?
2. What is a bind variable?
3. Are queries a type of List?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Q1: Theses interfaces are together with `RowCallbackHandler` frequently used by the `JdbcTemplate` when queering a database. Which interface you implement, how you implement it and which method you use in the `JdbcTemplate` depends on your database and what kind of query you would like to execute. From the [Spring API doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/) and some additional comments:

[RowMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html):

> An interface used by JdbcTemplate for mapping rows of a ResultSet on a per-row basis. Implementations of this interface perform the actual work of mapping each row to a result object

i.e. the `RowMapper` is commonly used to map objects when there is a one-to-one relationship between a row in the database and the resulting object.

[ResultSetExtractor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html):

> ResultSetExtractor object is typically stateless and thus reusable

Implementations of the `ResultSetExtractor` typically creates one object out of several rows, that is subsequently returned. It is stateless because the implementing class does not preserve any state between method calls.

[RowCallbackHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html):

> Implementations of this interface perform the actual work of processing each row [...] In contrast to a ResultSetExtractor, a RowCallbackHandler object is typically stateful: It keeps the result state within the object, to be available for later inspection.

The `RowCallbackHandler` is used for queries such as updating or deleting rows. Additionally, it is used when you need to track a state across the `ResultSet`, such as number of rows in the [RowCountCallbackHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCountCallbackHandler.html).